# Issue: cross domain hidden iframe produce a popup offering the download of the PHP script

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, cross-domain

This mainly affects all of IE's & Opera browsers, leaving FF, Chrome & Safari intact.

How can i disable the download popup?

TA

Answer (score 0):

Problem Resolved: had to use the right PHP header.

Previously used: header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8') - produced the download dialog.
Newly used: header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8') - no download dialog

YAY